# Iphone TabBarController Template

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

i am developing an application with the template of TabBarController.

The question is how can i set the second view to a NavigationController and set the root controller for that NavigationController.

I don't know if my question is sufficiently clear but i don't know how to explain it better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I set something like this up...

Tab Bar Controller
... 1st Tab View Controller
... 2nd Tab Navigation Controller
... ... View Controller
ect...

Make sure the .xib for the view controller inside the navigation controller has the proper class identity, it should be it's corresponding View Controller class file.

[image: MainWindow.xib]